# How to send a query result in CSV format?

Tags: sql, ssis

I am working on ETL and I have this below sql code in my SQL Task in SSIS package. This is how i have coded. I am selecting a data from a table and result of that query as file. I want this attachment sent in CSV format. How do i do it?

```
EXEC sp_send_dbmail @profile_name='default',
@recipients='dev@null.com',
@subject=@SUB,
@body=@BODY,

@query= 'SELECT [MID],[HID],[MeC],[LC],[RowCDate]
FROM [JBC].[dbo].[Table1] WHERE RowCDate >= GETDATE()
',
@attach_query_result_as_file=1
```

Any help will be very appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are using SSIS then why not use the features of SSIS to create a CSV file and the `Send Mail Task` to send the email?

Comment: Based on Requirement. This is the only way have to do it

Comment: I added an answer below that should format the query result as a CSV and added some more information about the sp_send_dbmail SP. Could you accept the answer if this worked for you?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Adding `@query_result_separator` should do the trick.

```
EXEC sp_send_dbmail @profile_name='default',
@recipients='dev@null.com',
@subject=@SUB,
@body=@BODY,

@query= 'SELECT [MID],[HID],[MeC],[LC],[RowCDate]
FROM [JBC].[dbo].[Table1] WHERE RowCDate >= GETDATE()
',
@attach_query_result_as_file = 1,
@query_attachment_filename   = 'Results.csv',
@query_result_separator      = ','
```

Adding `@query_result_no_padding = 1` might clean up the results a bit. All off the arguments can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190307.aspx)

Comment: The line with @attach_query_result_as_file=1 needs a comma at the end, otherwise the code throws an error.

Comment: Please note that these results will not be properly CSV formatted (escaped).  If any of your fields contain data with commas, you're in trouble

Comment: This answer does not work with opening CSV file in MS Excel. The separator is not enough, but need to specify the separator in the first line in the CSV file  as `sep=,`. Otherwise all the columns will show in one column in MS Excel.

Comment: FWIW, I found if your data contains commas then if you set `@temp = char(9);` and use the sp_send_dbmail parameter: `@query_result_separater = @temp;` you will have a tab-delimited file. Save it with the '.csv' extension regardless, and Excel will open the file on double-click (rather than having to open Excel then open or import the file and map fields to columns or specify the delimiter).

Answer (score 14):

```
@query='
SET NOCOUNT ON;
select ''sep=;''
select ''Col1'',''Col2'',''Col3'',''Col3''

select CONVERT(NVARCHAR,Col1),ISNULL(Col2, ''''),Col4
FROM ...
SET NOCOUNT OFF;
',

--Additional settings
@query_attachment_filename   = '*.csv',
@query_result_separator      = ';',
@attach_query_result_as_file = 1,
@query_result_no_padding     = 1,
@exclude_query_output        = 1,
@append_query_error          = 0,
@query_result_header         = 0;
```

Comment: Good idea about the NOCOUNT in the @query definition. +1

Comment: Inside a proc: `SELECT table.myColumn AS [sep=, 
myColumn]` with a normal hard return within the column alias.

Answer (score 7):

Adding

```
'[sep=,' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) ColumnName]
```

with result solved the issue

See [Source](http://www.purplefrogsystems.com/blog/2014/04/excel-doesnt-open-csv-files-correctly-from-sp_send_dbmail/)

Answer (score 4):

[This comment on purple frog](https://www.purplefrogsystems.com/blog/2014/04/excel-doesnt-open-csv-files-correctly-from-sp_send_dbmail/#comment-1739) indicates you can also use the tab character as a delimiter:

> ```
> DECLARE @tab char(1) = CHAR(9)
> EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail  
> @profile_name='donotreply' 
> ,@recipients ='xx@x'  
> ,@query= @query  
> ,@subject= 'xx'  
> ,@attach_query_result_as_file=1    
> ,@query_attachment_filename='xx.csv'    
> ,@query_result_separator=@tab
> ,@query_result_no_padding=1 –trim
> ,@query_result_width=32767 –stop wordwrap
> ```

Also looks like this answer's been posted already, my bad: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44315682/5758637

Answer (score 0):

Inside a proc:

```
SELECT 
table.myColumn AS [sep=, 
myColumn]
, table.myCol2
, table.myCol3...
```

with a normal hard return within the column alias after "sep=,".