# Want to execute sp_send_dbmail and send results in excel format

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel

I want to execute sp_send_dbmail and have results emailed in excel format. I have tried .csv and .txt but the results are not organized in neat columns.

This is my code

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
@profile_name = 'DBMail_profile',
@recipients = 'myaddress@me.com',
@subject = 'Test',
@query = N'EXEC DatabaseTest.dbo.test',
@attach_query_result_as_file = 1,
@query_result_width = 150,
@query_result_header= 1,
@query_attachment_filename = 'test.txt',
@importance = 'High',
@query_result_no_padding = 1
```

Also have tried this

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
@profile_name = 'DBMail_profile',
@recipients = 'myaddress@me.com',
@subject = 'Test',
@query = N'EXEC DatabaseTest.dbo.test',
@attach_query_result_as_file = 1,
@query_result_width = 150,
@query_result_header= 1,
@query_attachment_filename = 'test.csv',
@importance = 'High',
@query_result_no_padding = 1
```

I would like my results to be in a clean organized format. Do I have some of the parameters set incorrectly? Or is there a way to have attachment as .xls or .xlsx  file? I may be explaining incorrectly, I can answer any questions

Here is what I get back from .csv

```
EventDate FirstName LastName Department DeptCode OpCode Start Finish ElapsedTime Units UPH
```

---

```
2017-05-30 My Name Flat LL PP 07:00:00 07:15:00 00:15:00 700 2800
2017-05-31 His Name Maintenance FK PR 08:00:00 08:30:00 00:30:00 100 200
2017-05-30 Her Name Hang SD OC 12:32:00 14:31:00 01:59:00 23 12
```

When I have @query_attachment_file = 'test.xlsx' the attachment is identical to what the .csv provides.

I want to see attachment as such

```
2017-05-30  My   Name   Flat        LL  PP  07:00:00    07:15:00    00:15:00    700 2800
2017-05-31  His  Name   Maintenance FK  PR  08:00:00    08:30:00    00:30:00    100 200
2017-05-30  Her  Name   Hang        SD  OC  12:32:00    14:31:00    01:59:00    23  12
```

Stored Procedure .dbo.test looks like this

```
DECLARE 
@Now DATETIME,
@EndReportDate DATETIME,
@StartReportDate DATETIME,
@StartTime VARCHAR(16) ,
@EndTime VARCHAR(16)

SET @Now = GETDATE()
SET @EndReportDate = DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, @Now), -1)
SET @StartReportDate = DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, @Now), -9)
SET @StartTime = '01:00:00AM'
SET @EndTime = '11:59:00PM' 

SELECT 
TimeLog.EventDate AS 'EventDate'
 ,AssociateInfo.FirstName 'FirstName'
 ,AssociateInfo.LastName 'LastName'
 ,AssociateInfo.Department 'Department'
 ,TimeLog.DeptCode 'DeptCode'
 ,TimeLog.OpCode 'OpCode'
 ,TimeLog.StartTime 'Start'
 ,TimeLog.FinishTime 'Finish'
 ,ElapsedTime = convert(time(0),dateadd(second,datediff(second,StartTime,FinishTime),0)) 
,TimeLog.Units
,UPH = cast(isnull(Units / nullif(datediff(minute,StartTime,FinishTime)*1.0,0),0.0) *60 as decimal(10,0))
FROM dbo.TimeLog INNER JOIN dbo.AssociateInfo WITH (NOLOCK)
ON AssociateInfo.ID = TimeLog.ID

WHERE EventDate BETWEEN @StartReportDate + ' ' + @StartTime
                   AND     @EndReportDate + ' ' + @EndTime

ORDER BY  UPH DESC
```

Comment: What does the `test` stored procedure look like?

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209620/how-to-send-a-query-result-in-csv-format. TLDR: Use @query_result_separator to add a comma. Alternatively, you can send output of the query as an HTML mail.

Comment: @WEI_DBA I added the SP above :)

Comment: So basically you are dumping the query output into a flat file with no formatting. Give @SchmitzIT comment a try.

Comment: @WEI_DBA I am not exactly sure how to do that, can you please give an example that I can test?

Comment: See Damien's answer below. He's added the parameter.

Comment: Damian nailed it, that worked, I actually triple tabbed to get results in question,,,,,

Comment: @WEI_DBA Actually in spanish is Damian's haha, but yes! it was really tricky the issue that druiduiri wanted to do ;)

Comment: @SchmitzIT Your pointer helped me a lot to find the correct answer, plus one for sharing

Comment: Apologies @DamianLattenero. :)

Comment: @WEI_DBA That's ok! you made me laught indeed... I imagine for you my name should sound really rare

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this  TAB as the result separator.:

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
@profile_name = 'DBMail_profile',
@recipients = 'myaddress@me.com',
@subject = 'Test',
@query = N'EXEC DatabaseTest.dbo.test',
@attach_query_result_as_file = 1,
@query_result_width = 150,
@query_result_header= 1,
@query_attachment_filename = 'test.txt',
@importance = 'High',
@query_result_no_padding = 1,
@query_result_separator = '     '
```

Comment: Just tried it, If the if the data is different lengths the columns still report as before, not in straight columns

Comment: @DRUIDRUID Try tab as separator!

Comment: I didn't think of using a TAB space as result separator....Nice, I had to triple TAB and got the results I was looking for, Thanks a lot Damian :)

Comment: @DRUIDRUID You are welcome! don't forget accept the answer if it was useful! ;) with (✓)

Comment: This seems more like a hack than an actual answer.