# Sending a query results in csv file - file name

Tags: sql, sql-server, sp-send-dbmail

I am working on code that will send a results of my query via email. Mostly it works fine but I have a question: Is there any way that I could include a current date in the file name? Instead of having:

```
@query_attachment_filename = 'report.csv'
```

I would like to have something like:

```
report_getdate()\_.csv
```

I'm using SQL Server Management Studio 2016
Related topic: [How to send a query result in CSV format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209620/how-to-send-a-query-result-in-csv-format)

My query looks like this and it works well. Just need to change the name of the file

Any help appreciated. Thank you

```
DECLARE @AccountSite VARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @Query VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @AccountSite = '[sep=   ' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'AccountSite]'
SET @Query = 'SELECT
       [AccountSite] ' + @AccountSite + '
      ,[Account Name]
      ,[Title]
      ,[Status]
      ,[Opened Date]
      ,[Closed Date]
      ,[Geo]
      ,[Country]
      ,[Region]
      ,[Marketing Name]
      ,[Case Number]
  FROM [Reporting].[dbo].[Rep]'

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail  
     @profile_name = 'BI Server'
    ,@recipients = 'xyz@xyz.com'
    ,@query = @Query
    ,@subject = 'Report'
    ,@body = 'Attached is the latest extract of the report'
    ,@query_attachment_filename = 'report.csv'
    ,@query_result_separator = '    '
    ,@attach_query_result_as_file = 1
    ,@query_result_no_padding= 1
    ,@exclude_query_output =1
    ,@append_query_error = 0
    ,@query_result_header = 1
    ,@query_result_width = 32767;
```

Comment: Just define your filename as a variable first and use that instead of a string literal.

Comment: The file name can be what ever you want it to be (provided it's a valid file name), this is why there's a parameter for it: `@query_attachment_filename`. You are explicitly providing the value `'report.csv'` so that's the name the file gets. Just supply different value, like you are with `@query`.

Comment: Aside... you're sending a file with a `.csv` extension but `sp_send_dbmail` cannot generate a CSV file in any accepted sense of the definition, particularly with respect to [RFC4180 Common Format and MIME Type for Comma-Separated Values (CSV) Files](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4180). Try sending data containing `,`, `"` or linebreak characters and see how badly it fails. Consider external tools capable generating proper CSV files like SSRS (at least since SQL Server 2014 anyways) and PowerShell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define the report name before calling the SP

```
declare @attachment varchar(200) = CONCAT('report_',convert(varchar(25),getdate() ,102),'.csv');
```

After this, you can replace:

```
,@query_attachment_filename = 'report.csv'
```

by something like:

```
,@query_attachment_filename = @attachment
```

The `102` will format the date as `YYYY.MM.DD`, for other formats see: [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

NOTE: Some format will contain illegal characters for filenames, like i.e. 101, which formats as `mm/dd/yyyy`. But the `/` is not valid within a filename under Windows.

Comment: I did edit my answer, based on the comment from @DaleK

Comment: I`ts working. Thank you so much guys!